# .split removes tabs/spaces in string?

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to split a string up into separate lines with the following code, but for some reason it is also removing the spaces in the string.

```
Dim calculationText As String
calculationText = File.ReadAllText(fileName)

Dim fields() As String
fields = calculationText.Split(vbCrLf)
```

when i am in debugger mode, i look at fields, and every element has a line of the string but all the spaces and tabs are removed.

any reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reading from a file, can you use:

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim fields As New List(Of String)

    ' read file into list
    Using sr As System.IO.StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(filename)
        Try
            Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
                fields.Add(sr.ReadLine())
            Loop
        Finally
            If sr IsNot Nothing Then sr.Close()
        End Try
    End Using

    ' check results
    For Each line As String In fields
        Console.WriteLine(line)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Doh.. We posted this solution at the same time.  :-)  I'll remove mine because you actually have a code sample.

Comment: Um-- he could do this in a one-liner

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout:

```
Dim fields() As String = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
```

As for why string.Split() is doing weird things...

`vbCrLf` is a string, and there's not an overload for string.split that accepts a single string parameter.  If he were to turn on `Option Explicit` it wouldn't even compile, but since it's off, `vbCrLf` can be interpreted as an array of characters.  And in this code, that's exactly what happens:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim z As String = "The quick brown" & vbCrLf & " fox jumps over the lazy dogs."
    Dim a() As String = z.Split(vbCrLf)
    For Each c As String In a
        Console.WriteLine(c)
    Next
    Console.ReadKey(True)
End Sub
```

You'll see two line breaks between the 1st and 2nd parts of that string.  Something else is stripping out the spaces.  Can you share the larger code block?

Comment: Yeah, what Joel said. Go the one liner, it's cleaner & more concise. Plus, ReadAllLines will handle files with both cr, lf and crlf separators, and it's even byte order aware, so it's a better future proof solution.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta say I've never seen it do that, and I've used String.Split extensively. Are they really really gone, or is it a trick of the debugger?

There's not actually any .Split method that takes one string as the parameter, so the VB compiler would be doing "things" behind the scenes to pick a different overload. To try and force the correct overload, you could try `calculationText.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray())`. I doubt it will help, but you never know :-)